# How to see stdin of ansible commands

Tags: ansible

This is basically the same question as [how to see ansible stdout](https://serverfault.com/questions/537060/how-to-see-stdout-of-ansible-commands) only I wanted to see the commands generated and passed in by ansible. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the commands Ansible uses by appending multiple `-v` switches to the command line, so `-vvvv` is the most verbose logging possible.

Comment: all i see is ansible copying temp files and executing them.

Comment: Not only does adding multiple v's not let you see standard in, -vvvv is also not the most verbose possible. Try adding six v's to your command and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible modules are copied to $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ and cleared down after use.